# 'IEnumerable<>' does not contain a definition for '' and no extension method '' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<>' could be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to create online forum like below image

---

[image]

---

this is my Controller method

```
public ActionResult Discussion_Preview()
{

    int Discussion_ID = 1;


   var discussion_preview = (from d in db.AB_Discussion
                              where d.Discussion_ID == Discussion_ID
                              join dc in db.AB_DiscussionComments on d.Discussion_ID equals dc.Discussion_ID
                              join user_discussion in db.AspNetUsers on d.CreatedBy equals user_discussion.Id
                              join user_comments in db.AspNetUsers on dc.CreatedBy equals user_comments.Id
                              select new DiscussionPreview_Model
                              {
                                Disussion_ID = d.Discussion_ID,
                                Discussion_CreateDate = d.CreatedDate,
                                Discussion_CreateBy = user_discussion.UserName,
                                Discussion_Title = d.Discussion_Name,
                                Discussion_Description = d.Discription,
                                Comment_ID = dc.Comment_ID,
                                Comment_Description = dc.Comment_Discription,
                                Comment_CreateDate = dc.CreatedDate,
                                Comment_CreateBy = user_comments.UserName

                              });



    return View(discussion_preview);
}
```

Model Class

```
public class DiscussionPreview_Model
{
    public int Disussion_ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Discussion_CreateDate { get; set; }
    public string Discussion_CreateBy { get; set; }
    public string Discussion_Title { get; set; }
    public string Discussion_Description { get; set; }

    public int Comment_ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Comment_CreateDate { get; set; }
    public string Comment_CreateBy { get; set; }
    public string Comment_Description { get; set; }

}
```

View Page

```
@model IEnumerable<prjct.Models.DiscussionPreview_Model>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Discussion_Preview";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

 <h3>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Discussion_Title)</h3>

<div>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Discussion_Description)</div>
<div>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Discussion_CreateDate)  @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Discussion_CreateDate)</div>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{

    <fieldset>
        <legend></legend>

        <h4>Comments</h4>
        <div class="display-field">@item.Comment_Description</div>
        <div class="display-field">@item.Comment_CreateBy : @item.Comment_CreateDate </div>

    </fieldset>
}
```

When debug above application I'm getting below error message

> 'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Discussion_Title' and no extension method 'Discussion_Title' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Your `DisplayFor()` helpers need to be inside the `foreach` loop. But my best guess is what you really want to do is display a `DiscussionPreview_Model` and a collection of all comments associated with it?

Comment: but only I have one discussion title and discussion description

Comment: No you don't, you have a collection (that's what `IEnumerable` is)

Comment: but I want to display one discussion title and discussion description and then loop the comments , how can I do that ?

Comment: Then you need to redesign your model. You want properties such as `Title`, `Description` etc, and `IEnumerable<Comment> Comments` where `Comment` contains properties such as `CreateBy` and `Description`

Comment: Thanks I did you said this is code snippet https://dotnetfiddle.net/XOkleA

But Then Im having problem in Contoller class how can I void it

Comment: You cant use a DotNetFiddle to refer to your database context :) You just need to modify your query so that you get the first `AB_Discussion` that matches `Discussion_ID` and populate the main properties of the model, and then get all associated comments to populate the `Comments` collection. And stop that awful naming - just `ID` not `Disussion_ID` :)

Comment: bit of lack of knowledge to modify my controller class linq query can you help me with that

Comment: If you modify you fiddle to add the models associated with `AB_Discussion` and `AB_DiscussionComments` I'll have a look for you a bet later

Comment: okay , thanks , As I feel since comments properties out of the DiscussionPreview_Model Im getting error in current Linq query as `'DiscussionPreview_Model' does not contain a definition for 'Comment_ID,...'`

Comment: I tried to do this in this way just look at the code snippet https://dotnetfiddle.net/xroRV5 but then its not show the Discussion_Description or Discussion_CreateBy only it shows  Discussion_Title

Comment: I can't help much because you have not posted the data models, but start by breaking this down into 2 parts. Get the `discussion` object from `AB_Discussion` based on the `Discussion_ID` value and populate `Title`, `Description` etc. The query the `AB_DiscussionComments` tables to get the comments associated with `Discussion_ID` value and populate the `Comments` property with the results.

Answer (score 4):

Your model is of type `IEnumerable<prjct.Models.DiscussionPreview_Model>` and you're trying to use it like `prjct.Models.DiscussionPreview_Model`, which doesn't work. You will have to loop the `IEnumerable` and then use the `Html.DisplayFor` for each of the elements inside the `IEnumerable`, like you're doing in the comments part.

Comment: '@model IEnumerable<prjct.Models.DiscussionPreview_Model>' rename to '@model prjct.Models.DiscussionPreview_Model'

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use as

```
<h3>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Discussion_Title)</h3>
```

but here your model is IEnumerable, so you are having two options.

#### Option 1

If you are sure that Discussion_Title, Discussion_Description, and Discussion_CreateDate is same for all record then you have to use as

```
<h3>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ElementAt<DiscussionPreview_Model>(0).Discussion_Title)</h3>
```

and same for other 2 column, but in this case at least one record must be there otherwise you have to check for count of record before using it.

#### Option 2

Try to create the model in such a way that like

```
public class Discssion
{
    public string Discussion_Title { get; set; }
    public string Discussion_Description { get; set; }
    public string Comment_CreateBy { get; set; }
    public List<DiscussionPreview> DiscussionPreviews{ get;set;}
}

public class DiscussionPreview
{
    public class Comment_Description{ get; set; }
    .....
}
```

and use it in same way in your view.

Let me know you need more details.

Comment: Thnks.I tried both your options seems like not working

Comment: `'IEnumerable<DiscussionPreview_Model>' does not contain a definition for 'Discussion_Title' and no extension method 'Discussion_Title' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<DiscussionPreview_Model>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Please put class with full path (IEnumerable<DiscussionPreview_Model>)--> IEnumerable<<your class namespace>.DiscussionPreview_Model>

Please let me know if still you are facing any problem

Comment: That how its existing, with full path :((

Comment: for me @Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.ElementAt<prjct.Models.DiscussionPreview_Model>(0).Discussion_Title) is working

Comment: @Ravi I have same error please help me to solve same error I need to show as master header of the page and details down this is my question link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62012068/cs1061-ienumerableorders-tables-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-labviewr , but i dont need to loop it and i need to get one value only